# Angular 4 signup firebase First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

The console gives me the following error:

[image]

Have already tried several solutions that I found on Google, but it still does not work.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html'
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  signUp(email: string, password: string){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error:any) {
    // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried debugging and checking what the values are at runtime?

Comment: what is the value of email @ runtime did you check

Answer (score 2):

It might be problem with Javascript types. Firebase Auth requires that type of argument is `string`. Observables, String Object and other string like objects are not actually type of `string`.

```
typeof new String("email@email.io")  // "object"
typeof String(new String("email@email.io"))  // "string"
typeof "email@email.io"  // "string"
```

You can try something like this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String(email), String(password))
```

Comment: your solution work but now it give that email is badly formatted . what can be reason behind that ?